# r10k puppetfile install hang / stuck

Tags: puppet, r10k

So i'm trying to install a lot of module (66 in total) from a single Puppetfile and after every 7-9 modules installed the process hang up or it seem that it's stops working.

I found a temporal solution tot this problem, but it's a bit of a pain.

I have to kill the r10k process and remove the module that it was trying to install from the ~/.r10k/git folder

```
user@ubuntu:~$ ps -aux | grep r10k
user   20294  0.1  0.1 234032 30728 pts/1    Sl+  13:03   0:00 /usr/bin/ruby2.5 /home/user/.ruby/bin/r10k puppetfile install -v
user   27143  0.0  0.0  26028  4004 ?  Ss 13:15 0:00 git clone ssh://git@bitbucket.com:/bla/crashed-repository.git /home/user/Documents/Projects/repository --reference /home/ser/.r10k/git/ssh---git@bitbucket.com-7999-crashed-repository.git

user@ubuntu:~$ kill 20294
user@ubuntu:~$ kill 27143

user@ubuntu:~$ cd ~/.r10k/git/

user@ubuntu:~/.../git$ ls -la
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 37 user user 4096 ago 23 13:18 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 user user 4096 ago 23 12:46 ..
drwxr-xr-x  7 user user 4096 ago 23 12:46 ssh---git@bitbucket.com-7999-respository_one.git
drwxr-xr-x  7 user user 4096 ago 23 12:46 ssh---git@bitbucket.com-7999-respository_two.git
drwxr-xr-x  7 user user 4096 ago 23 12:46 ssh---git@bitbucket.com-7999-respository_three.git
drwxr-xr-x  7 user user 4096 ago 23 12:46 ssh---git@bitbucket.com-7999-respository_four.git
. 
.
.
drwxr-xr-x  7 user user 4096 ago 23 12:46 ssh---git@bitbucket.com-7999-crashed-repository.git

user@ubuntu:~/.../git$ rm -r ssh---git@bitbucket.com-7999-crashed-repository.git
```

And after that run it again until it hang up again, and so on until all the modules are installed.

I've found a thread on the [puppetlabs/r10k github](https://github.com/puppetlabs/r10k/issues/650) that explains why this happens, but no solution to the problem.

If anyone know how to do a "try/catch" while installing multiple puppet modules so that this issue doesn't show up anymore i'll be very grateful.

Comment: You could probably write a Ruby wrapper around r10k for that purpose. Just load in the gem and create a cli around its commands with the desired functionality.

Comment: @MattSchuchard unfortunately I didn't work with Ruby at all until now, more of a python guy, but I will look it on-line and try to figure it out. But thanks for the idea that's a big help, now I know more or less how to "attack" this issue :)

Comment: Yeah I was looking at tearing an API out of r10k at some point to spoof g10k as an interface to Code Manager via the go/ruby gRPC(?) interface, so I know you can treat its CLI/Command methods as an unsupported API. It depends on how much you can code around that to make your custom CLI stable. If you are really more comfortable with Python, then there is a RPC between Ruby and Python somewhere.

Comment: thanks @MattSchuchard I will look into it